# <__NSCFDictionary: 0x1557f400> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have ios 7 application that is running on iphone 4. I have a weird problem, where application crashes inside for loop, because of the error in the title. I checked on SO and it says that error occurs when you change object over which you are iterating.
So I copied both variables that I use to temp variables but problem still occurs. 
Problem happen when first iteration is finished.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary * badges = [defaults objectForKey:@"badges"];
    NSMutableDictionary *newBadges = badges;
    for(NSString* key in badges)
    {
        NSDictionary* badge = [badges objectForKey:key];
        if([[badge objectForKey:@"achived"]  isEqual: @"NO"])
        {
            if([self checkBadgeCondition:badge])
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *tempBadge = [badge mutableCopy];
                [self showAlertBadge:badge];
                [tempBadge setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"achived"];
                [newBadges setObject:tempBadge forKey:[tempBadge objectForKey:@"name"]];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's happening inside of `checkBadgeCondition`? Also, you might want to convert to Objective-C 2.0 syntax. I.e., `[tempBadge setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"archived"]` can be simplified to `tempBage[@"archived"] = @"YES"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newBadges = badges
```

This isn't a copy, it's just another reference to the same thing. You also should expect a dictionary (or array) coming out of user defaults to be mutable. So, make a mutable copy of it here

```
newBadges = [badges mutableCopy]
```